# Creating some partition functions and schemes for one table

Tags: sql-server

I don't know how it's possible to create 5 partition functions that are used by 2 partition schemes on a single table. My example table has 5 integer columns and I'd want each to be used with one function. Column 1,3,5 will be moved to the filegroup X per partition scheme PS1 and the rest to the filegroup Y per partition PS2.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [func1] (int)  
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (1, 100); 

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [func2] (int)  
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (100, 200); 

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [func3] (int)  
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (200, 300); 

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [func4] (int)  
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (300, 400); 

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [func5] (int)  
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (400);
```

And the partition schemes,

```
ALTER DATABASE myDB
ADD FILEGROUP X;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE myDB
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = _X,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\X.ndf',  
    SIZE = 10MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5%  
)
TO FILEGROUP X;  
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS1] 
AS PARTITION ([func1], [func3], [func5]) TO (X)
GO

ALTER DATABASE myDB
ADD FILEGROUP Y;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE myDB
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = _Y,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Y.ndf',  
    SIZE = 10MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5%  
)
TO FILEGROUP Y;  
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS] 
AS PARTITION ([func2], [func4]) TO (Y)
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood how partitioning works.  Each table sits on one partition scheme.  Each partition scheme uses one partition function.

If a table has multiple indexes, each can be on a separate partition scheme.

Also it's rarely useful to put partitions on separate filegroups.  There are specific scenarios where it's useful, but it's often unnecessary.

Comment: `If a table has multiple indexes, each can be on a separate partition scheme.`
Does that mean one table can have many partition schemes? I have 5 columns and each can be indexed differently on each scheme. Each scheme can be used with 1 function, so I can have 5 functions. ???

Comment: Yes.  If your table has multiple indexes, they can be on different partition schemes, with different partition functions.  But what are you hoping to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Thank you, I would only want to know if it's possible.